# Custom ListBox which includes other controls

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, listbox, custom-controls

I need a custom ListBox which contains three elements in each row:
checkbox, string and picturebox.
How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You can make dynamic controls to panels via by code but that is lengthy i would suggest you use a grid like in the following links because i think this is what you are trying to achieve.
http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/display-images-gridview-from-database.html,
http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/adding-a-gridview-column-of-checkboxes-cs

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a grid control if possible. The DataGridView will do this, but the commercial version may work better.

Another possible solution is to override the paint event on the checked listbox and create a custom Owner Drawn control http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/Owner_drawn_ListBox.aspx , or go commercial.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is by changing the DrawMode from Normal to OwnerDrawFixed or OwnerDrawVariable and do the drawing yourself in the DrawItem event for the listbox.

For the CheckBox, look at ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(...) or CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(...)

For the string, e.Graphics.DrawString(...)

For the picturebox, e.Graphics.DrawImage(...)